# Is this burnt from fertilizer?

Tags: diseases, leaves, plant-care, shrubs, fertilizer

I plant this about two months ago and now it is showing yellow leaves

[image]

[image]

I think it is due to some powder-like fertilizer I put around the root (5 inches away) and bury in the compost when I planted it.

Is this some burnt effect? If not, what is it?

Comment: Which fertilizer? I see them in forests, so I think they do not requires much fertilizers. But they have more problem with soil: they like alkaline soil (so not acid), but not all alkaline soil are good for them). To me it is more about acidity, but we need more information.

Comment: Have you kept it well watered since planting it?